# Creating a JSON in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF in PySpark

```
|id |Name   |Age |
|-- |------ |--- |
|1  |John   |31  |
|2  |Sam    |34  |
|3  |Chris  |28  |
```

which I need to change to below DF,

```
|id         |       Name        |       Age     |
| ------    | ----------------  | -----------   |
|{'v':1}    |   {'v':'John'}    |   {'v':31}    |
|{'v':2}    |   {'v':'Sam'}     |   {'v':34}    |
|{'v':3}    |   {'v':'Chris'}   |   {'v':28}    |
```

Although this code is working in Python but not in PySpark :

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: [{'value':i} for i in x] , axis=0)
```

What would be most efficient way to do it in PySpark, as there are more than 50 columns and 10 such tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create_map` to create map columns :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select(*[F.create_map(F.lit("v"), F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df1.show()
+--------+------------+---------+
|      id|        Name|      Age|
+--------+------------+---------+
|[v -> 1]| [v -> John]|[v -> 31]|
|[v -> 2]|  [v -> Sam]|[v -> 34]|
|[v -> 3]|[v -> Chris]|[v -> 28]|
+--------+------------+---------+
```

And use `to_json` to get json string from map:

```
df1.select(*[F.to_json(c).alias(c) for c in df1.columns]).show()

#+-------+-------------+--------+
#|     id|         Name|     Age|
#+-------+-------------+--------+
#|{"v":1}| {"v":"John"}|{"v":31}|
#|{"v":2}|  {"v":"Sam"}|{"v":34}|
#|{"v":3}|{"v":"Chris"}|{"v":28}|
#+-------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: This solution is perfect, except to_json is putting a double quote on integer as well, which should not happen. Any hack?

Comment: @MukundRanjan any reason to prefer single quotes? it will be not valid json in this case.

Comment: @MukundRanjan you might want to use `format_string` function: `df.select(*[F.format_string("{'v':'%s'}", c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()`

Comment: If the similar things need to be done in Python3 what could be the best way, `df = df.apply(lambda x: [{'value':i} for i in x] , axis=0)`.. Although this code is doing it but it is putting value and column_value in single quote, in valid JSON it should be double quote. if there is any quote in column_value then a escape character should be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each column to a struct with a field called `value`, and convert to json:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select([F.to_json(F.struct(F.col(c).alias('value'))).alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df2.show()
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|           id|             Name|           Age|
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|{"value":"1"}| {"value":"John"}|{"value":"31"}|
|{"value":"2"}|  {"value":"Sam"}|{"value":"34"}|
|{"value":"3"}|{"value":"Chris"}|{"value":"28"}|
+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
```